# Scala Return abstract class

Tags: scala, abstract-class, parent-child

Like in Java I could have access to a new parameter of a child in scala why I dont have access?

```
abstract class superclass

class class1(c: Int) extends superclass

class class2(a: String) extends superclass


def foo(i: Int): superclass ={
  if(i == 1){
    return new class1(1)
  }
  else {
    return new class2("as")
  }
}

val cla = foo(1)

cla.c ??
```

How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: There is no issue. Your `superclass` does not have a member `c`, and the compiler is telling you about your mistake. Unclear what you're asking. By the way, both in Java and in Scala, the class names are written in PascalCase.

Comment: How can i have access to the c then and write the same idea in code?

Comment: Declare the return type of `foo` to be `class1`, make sure that `foo` indeed returns `class1` and never `class2`.

Comment: But thats what i want to return 2 different classes in one function

Comment: If you want to return `class2`, then why do you want to access the member "`c`"? Your `class2` does not have a member called "`c`". And even if it had, it's not declared in the interface of the superclass.

Comment: I have a more complicate system that i need to create 2 different classes and depends by the json that i i will get as a response from an api request.

Comment: I don't know what your more complicated systems is supposed to look like, but the above example is just a piece of code that obviously should not compile, and which indeed does not compile, so it's unclear what you are expecting from it or what you're asking. Probably you should update your question with more relevant details. Looks like XY-problem so far.

Comment: I am just asking how can I re-write this to work having a child classes return from a function and have access to their parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem here is that `class1` does not have a member `c` in the first place so even this won't work:

```
val c1 = new class1(3)
c1.c // Error: value c is not a member of class1
```

`c` is a parameter to the constructor but is not a member.

You can fix this by making it a case class, which does make constructor parameters into members:

```
case class class1(c: Int) extends superclass
```

Once this is fixed, you still can't access member `c` from an instance of `superclass` because `superclass` doesn't have a member called `c`. This is true of Java just as much as it is true of Scala. So you can't directly access the member `c` of the result of `foo`.

However you can use `match` to work out which subclass of `superclass` is returned, like this:

```
val cla = foo(1)

cla match {
  case class1(c) =>
    println(s"It is class1, c = $c")
  case class2(a) =>
    println(s"It is class2, a is $a")
  case _ =>
    println("It is some other class")
}
```

This will print "It is class1, c = 1", while changing `foo(1)` to `foo(2)` will print "It is class2, a is as".

Other issues: Class names should start with a capital letter (not required, but `match` becomes confusing with lower-case class names), and the `return` keyword is not required and doesn't always behave the way you might expect.